# Track file selection in file input

Tags: laravel, forms, file, alpine.js

I have Laravel/Blade form with simple file upload functionality:

```
Upload: {{ Form::file('logo') }}
```

I use AlpineJS, and I want to track file selection - when user selects some file, framework will be notified. I tried following:

```
Upload: {{ Form::file('logo', ["x-ref"=>"file", "@change"=>"console.log($refs.file.value)"]) }}
```

But this does not work because the `$ref` cannot be defined inside blade's `{{}}` tags. Can somebody advise how to track file selection? Thank you.

Comment: Which `Form` class is that? Can't you just give an id to input element and add an event listener to it on javascript?

Comment: Try escaping the *$*:  \$ref